# Why would I ever need to cancelAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript, animation

I don't understand why the API includes `cancelAnimationFrame()`, because
I can stop the animation by setting the `continue` variable like this:

```
function draw(timestamp) {
  if (continue == true) { requestAnimationFrame(draw); }
}
```

So the questions is **under what circumstances should I use cancelAnimationFrame()?**

Comment: the concept behind the api is to communicate intent to the device. I suspect that it is in these regards.

Comment: Your code demonstrates how to conditionally schedule the next animation frame, but not how to cancel a previously scheduled animation callback. There may be situations (e.g. when another, mutually-exclusive animation is triggered by the user) where you may want to cancel the pending animation callbacks before scheduling the new ones (something akin to jQuery's `stop()` method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an important point of reference. A (dated) (Candidate Recommendation) Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#definitions

> Associated with every Document is an animation frame request callback list, which is a list of  tuples. handle is an integer `^[long]` that uniquely identifies the entry in the list. callback is a FrameRequestCallback object. Initially, the animation frame request callback list for a Document is empty.

Also, lets bear in mind that the target audience of these specs are user-agent developers. It's in the implemention of these specs that user-agent provides an API to us (app developers) to interface with/to.

*Note the **every Document*** sentiment above; you can have multible documents in a `window`, or ***context***. You can have multiple ***contexts*** in a browsing context.

So, how does that relate to **every Document**? Well, the (Recommendation) spec references the **Process Model**, which essentially dumps all these lists into an empty list, and perform a **callback invoking algorithm** on the results of that 'preserved' list.. but, again, this is probably not a concern to us as app developers; ***I THINK**, we, as app developers, aren't going to be tracking and maintaining even Document.FrameRequestList instances in and throughout multiple documents of our own `window` *context*. We just interface with the API, which is accessible on `window`.

Now, lets summarize what `requestAnimationFrame(<function>)` does in effect, **AND** what it *returns*.

Calling `requestAnimationFrame` and providing a `function` as a **callback**, adds an **entry** (`<handler,FrameRequestCallback>` or `<long, "an object, with a cancelled member, that encapsulates your function">`) into an **animation frame request callback list**. **`requestAnimationFrame` returns the `Handler [long]`**.

According to the aforementioned spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#dom-windowanimationtiming-cancelanimationframe),

> The cancelAnimationFrame method is used to cancel a previously made request to schedule an animation frame update.

One can infer, that by calling `cancelAnimationFrame` and supplying the (presumably previously stored) `handle` as a parameter, you ***remove*** an entry from the **animation frame request callback list**, **BUT** that isn't the case.

> When cancelAnimationFrame(handle) is called, the user agent must set the cancelled flag to true for the callback registered on this ***Document*** whose *handle* is **handle**. The **cancelled** flag is set whether the callback is in a **animation frame request callback list** or not. If there is no callback with the given handle, then this function does nothing.

So the `handle` you provide in your `cancelAnimationFrame` doesn't modify the list. it sets the cancelled flag to true 'on the callback'.. which really keeps it from running. This is reasonable because the aforementioned (above) **Processing Model**.

---

So, to your question (and in regards to a particular comment on your question) skipping over the adding of an entry to an **animation frame request callback list** of a document, using `requestAnimationFrame` doesn't keep existing `scheduled` entries  (or existing entries whose cancelled flag is false) from running. There is a 'larger' context and processing model to consider (which includes document-page visibility attributes).

It was mentioned as a comment in your question that there are particular scenerios that you might want to cancel the schedule frame requests - but better reasoning to do it is for the unintentional aspects and considerations.

In short, if you're going to use the API to request frame updates that do callbacks, use the API to cancel/stop said update requests and stop the callback.

Answer (score 0):

**FWIW and to complete the accepted answer:**

I came here to find out if a function scheduled with `requestAnimationFrame`, which mutates an element already removed (aka. unmounted) from the DOM when executed, would throw an error. It doesn't, ie.:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('element'); 
setTimeout(() => el.remove(), 20); 
setTimeout(() => {
  el.style.transform = 'scale(2)'
  console.log(el instanceof HTMLElement) // el is kept in memory but removed from the DOM
, 40) // true`.
```

To sum up, you SHOULD use `cancelAnimationFrame` to prevent side effects from a function auto-scheduled with `requestAnimationFrame`, and you CAN optionally use it to (micro-)optimize by avoiding its execution even if it has no side effects.